# Permanent link to an audio file (googleDrive)

Tags: api, windows-phone-8, google-drive-realtime-api

I'm developing a player for playing audio from the "cloud." Having question, if it is possible to obtain permanent link to an audio file to play without regular re-authorization (googleDrive)?

Comment: you still have to do the OAuth stuff but the file link will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the file list back from Google drive theres a field called `AlternateLink`  this apears to have a link something like this:

```
https://docs.google.com/file/d/{SomehashStuff}/edit?usp=drivesdk
```

If I dump that link into a browser it opens the file for me.  Now this will probably only work if you have access to that file and are loged into google at the time.    So if you save that link my bet is that you will be able to use it later to open the file.  But this will probably only work if you have access to the file and are loged into google with the browser you are using to open the link.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. 
You say: "re loged into google with the browser you are using to open the link."
I developing mobile app (windows phone). I am getting audio file from stream (not browser)

Comment: Note im not a mobile programer but i have read a bit about it. My thinking is that if the phone is loged in to google you have access to it.  What happends if you ask the app to open that link assuming its a audio file will it open the audio file in a audio program?